# Custom GroupBox with custom TextColor, BorderColor and Transparent BackColor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparency, groupbox

I'm using `WinForms`. In my form I have a `GroupBox`. This is a ***custom*** group box. I wanted a transparent background for the `groupbox`. I'm having issues creating a transparent background for the `groupbox` The problem with this code is i keep on getting an error when i set the group box `backcolor` to transparent.

> Error: Control does not support transparent background colors.

`g.Clear(BackColor = Color.Transparent);` (This is the line that is giving me the problem)

```
    private void DrawGroupBox(GroupBox box, Graphics g, Color textColor, Color borderColor)
    {
        if (box != null)
        {
            Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);
            Brush borderBrush = new SolidBrush(borderColor);
            Pen borderPen = new Pen(borderBrush);
            SizeF strSize = g.MeasureString(box.Text, box.Font);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(box.ClientRectangle.X,
                                           box.ClientRectangle.Y + (int)(strSize.Height / 2),
                                           box.ClientRectangle.Width - 1,
                                           box.ClientRectangle.Height - (int)(strSize.Height / 2) - 1);

            // Clear text and border
            g.Clear(BackColor = Color.Transparent);

            // Draw text
            g.DrawString(box.Text, box.Font, textBrush, box.Padding.Left, 0);

            // Drawing Border
            //Left
            g.DrawLine(borderPen, rect.Location, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height));
            //Right
            g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y), new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + rect.Height));
            //Bottom
            g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height), new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y + rect.Height));
            //Top1
            g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X, rect.Y), new Point(rect.X + box.Padding.Left, rect.Y));
            //Top2
            g.DrawLine(borderPen, new Point(rect.X + box.Padding.Left + (int)(strSize.Width), rect.Y), new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Y));
        }
    }

    private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GroupBox box = sender as GroupBox;
        DrawGroupBox(box, e.Graphics, Color.Red, Color.Blue);
    }
```

`g.Clear(groupBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent);`

If i do this i get:

> This example consists of a `Panel` with a dice image inside the panel,
>   and the custom `Groupbox`.

[image]

Comment: The question is not clear to me. If you're trying to change the border color, then why is the question regarding the background color?

Comment: I wanted to make a custom `groupbox` I wanted to change the colors of the border and the text. I also wanted to have a transparent background, but i kept having issues setting up the transparent background i posted up an image. @DeeDee

Comment: I suggest dropping the `GroupBox` and using a `Panel` subclass instead. -  It will still group `RadioButtons` and you can style it any way you like..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`GroupBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.groupbox?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) control supports transparent background unless you use `System` as `FlatStyle`, but for the border color, you need to paint the group box yourself.

You can inherit from `GroupBox` and then because `GroupBox` supports `Transparent` background, so you can simply override the [`OnPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and render your group box without doing any thing about background.

**Code**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
public class GroupBoxEx : GroupBox
{
    private Color borderColor = Color.Black;
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set { borderColor = value; this.Invalidate(); }
    }
    private Color textColor = Color.Black;
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get { return textColor; }
        set { textColor = value; this.Invalidate(); }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GroupBoxState state = base.Enabled ? GroupBoxState.Normal : 
            GroupBoxState.Disabled;
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsTranslateTransform | 
            TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | 
            TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
        Color titleColor = this.TextColor;
        if (!this.ShowKeyboardCues) 
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.HidePrefix;
        if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes) 
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft | TextFormatFlags.Right;
        if (!this.Enabled) 
            titleColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        DrawUnthemedGroupBoxWithText(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, base.Width,
            base.Height), this.Text, this.Font, titleColor, flags, state);
        RaisePaintEvent(this, e);
    }
    private void DrawUnthemedGroupBoxWithText(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, 
        string groupBoxText, Font font, Color titleColor, 
        TextFormatFlags flags, GroupBoxState state)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = bounds;
        rectangle.Width -= 8;
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, groupBoxText, font, 
            new Size(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height), flags);
        rectangle.Width = size.Width;
        rectangle.Height = size.Height;
        if ((flags & TextFormatFlags.Right) == TextFormatFlags.Right)
            rectangle.X = (bounds.Right - rectangle.Width) - 8;
        else
            rectangle.X += 8;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, groupBoxText, font, rectangle, titleColor, flags);
        if (rectangle.Width > 0)
            rectangle.Inflate(2, 0);
        using (var pen = new Pen(this.BorderColor))
        {
            int num = bounds.Top + (font.Height / 2);
            g.DrawLine(pen, bounds.Left, num - 1, bounds.Left, bounds.Height - 2);
            g.DrawLine(pen, bounds.Left, bounds.Height - 2, bounds.Width - 1,
                bounds.Height - 2);
            g.DrawLine(pen, bounds.Left, num - 1, rectangle.X - 3, num - 1);
            g.DrawLine(pen, rectangle.X + rectangle.Width + 2, num - 1, 
                bounds.Width - 2, num - 1);
            g.DrawLine(pen, bounds.Width - 2, num - 1, bounds.Width - 2,
               bounds.Height - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Some note about the control**

- The `GroupBox` control supports transparent background unless you use `System` as `FlatStyle`.
- You can also inherit from `Panel` because is is a container control and also supports transparent back color.
- If you need to make a custom control that inherits form `Control` to support transparent background, you should add `SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);` in constructor.
- Above code is based on drawing code of original `GroupBox` and I made some changes to fit your requirements and also remains like original `GroupBox`.
- `BorderColor` property added to support custom border color.
- Using `ForeColor` property of `GroupBox` to render the title of control may be annoying because `ForeColor` is an ambient property and will be inherited by child controls. So I created another property like `TextColor` for this purpose. (Children of group box will use fore color of group box by default, unless you change their fore color property.)

Comment: Thank you once again Reza for explaining how its done, and giving a good picture of the example!

Comment: I'm trying to follow this example without much luck.  I created the derived class, it shows up in my toolbox as a component and I'm able to drag it onto the form.  However I'm not getting transparency.  Is there a property or something I'm forgetting to set?

Comment: Ah, I found it.  Set BackColor to Web | Transparent.  But I can do that with a regular GroupBox control.  Why do I need the inherited code?  Sorry if that's a newbie question.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter For a *normal* group box you can set the `BackColor` to `Transparent` simply. The point of this question and answer is a *custom*  group box with different `BorderColor` and `TextColor`.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tweak:

inside the form's constructor:

```
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
```

then in your code:

```
g.Clear(groupBox1.TransparencyKey = Color.Red);
```

Comment: Would i have to use something for the TransparencyKye, because it keeps on giving me a red squiggly line underneath it.

Comment: It says `GroupBox` does not contain a definition for `TransparencyKey` and no extension method `TranspanencyKey` accepting a first argument of type `GroupBox` coulld be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: write this inside the form constructor 'this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;'

Comment: The constructor code works fine. When i add `g.Clear(groupBox1.TransparencyKey = Color.Red);` this section of the code in my DrawGroupBox method `TransparencyKey` still gives me a red squiggly line.

Comment: If the OP use `TransparencyKey` it makes the whole region of `GroupBox` to be transparent and you will see what is behind the form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SetStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

```
public partial class myGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    public TranspBackground()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `GroupBox` control supports transparent background unless you use `System` as `FlatStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many if statements as you wish, for my end it worked perfectly. Just with this two functions I made it work.

```
private void redrawTransparent() {
    var change = GetAll(this);

    foreach (Control control in change) {
        if (control is System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox) {
            groupBox.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            groupBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
        if(control is System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage) {
            tabPage.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

And this functions gets all the controls from a form.

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control) {
    // Cast the controls collection to IEnumerable<Control>
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    // Use SelectMany to recursively call GetAll for each nested control and concatenate the results
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl)).Concat(controls);
}
```