# How to make a custom control be updated in designer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a custom control derived from Panel.
Everything works fine, except that in designer my control is only redrawn when it loses focus.
What am I missing?

Here is the code of CustomControl.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Picwing
{
    public partial class xPanel : Panel
    {
        private SizeF textSize;

        public xPanel() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public override string Text {
            get { return base.Text; }
            set { base.Text = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
            textSize = pe.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font);
            pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(ForeColor, 1), pe.ClipRectangle.X, pe.ClipRectangle.Y + textSize.Height / 2, pe.ClipRectangle.Width - 1, pe.ClipRectangle.Height - textSize.Height / 2 - 1);
            pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), 5, 0, textSize.Width, textSize.Height);
            pe.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), pe.ClipRectangle.X + 6, pe.ClipRectangle.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a print screen taken after moving label1 inside xPanel1, before it loses focus.
[image]

Comment: Could you print screen that?

Comment: You forgot to post codes of your control.

Comment: Did you register the OnPaint Event with '+=" ?

Comment: Don't use `pe.ClipRectangle`. Use `DisplayRectangle` or `ClientRactangle` instead, based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because of using `pe.ClipRectangle` while painting on control. 
Don't use `pe.ClipRectangle`. Use `DisplayRectangle` or `ClientRactangle` instead, based on your requirement.

When you draw in `pe.ClipRectangle` bounds, as you can see, the drawing will be done on the smallest invalidated part of your control.

Note:

- You don't need to have `InitializeComponent();` in constructor unless you use designer of your panel component to add some other components to it.
- If you used `DisplayRectangle`, then in the `FillRectangle` method, instead of `0,5` use `DisplayRectangle.X + 5, DisplayRectangle.Y`.
- If you are trying you draw a custom `GroupBox`, you can take a look at [Custom GroupBox BackColor to Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34567212/3110834)

Comment: Thank you very much. I've used ClientRectangle and the problem is solved.