# How can I style a Label like a GroupBox header?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am lookin for a way to style a label like a groupbox, more specifically the header of a groupbox. Yeah, I know, strange description.

So what I actually want is a single-line label that has a short windows-theme-colored-line (vertically centered) before the text and a filling line to the right border after the text. Like a groupbox-header, but without the left/right/bottom stuff. More or less like this:

`------ MyLabelText ---------------------------------`

I am pretty sure that I've used such a control before but I'cant remember the name or if it was .NET or another language... :(

So...

- Is there a built-in control?
- If I have to extend the `Label` class...
- ...is the width/space from left-label-border to the starting of the text static and always `8px`?
- ...how do I get the color of the line - is it always `SystemColors.ControlLight`?
- ...is there something else that I should consider related to theme-stuff in windows

Comment: The color is the same. You can check by changing the backcolor of your form. It remains the same. Just draw everything. It is not so hard.

Comment: This is *not* about beeing a hard problem. I already have a component that renders like the groupbox control in windows 10. But it should fit into other windows version styles as well...

Comment: Different versions of windows have different styles of groupbox. You cant have one for all. eg win xp can have a checkbox or a collapse marker or round edges etc..

Comment: You can use the code which is used to draw custom border for group box in this post: [Custom GroupBox with custom TextColor, BorderColor and Transparent BackColor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34567212/3110834)